Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Ljava/lang/String;)
now I want to load my spark pipeline model saved in the path(C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\kaggle\classification\dt) which contains two dirsmetadata and stages. But when I try loading my model in my maven project(using spark and springboot), the error occured in the terminal:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/nativeio/NativeIO$POSIX$Stat;
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.getStat(NativeIO.java:608)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfoByNativeIO(RawLocalFileSystem.java:934)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:848)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:816)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocatedFileStatus.<init>(LocatedFileStatus.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:2199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:2179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:332)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:300)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:300)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$take$1(RDD.scala:1428)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1422)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$first$1(RDD.scala:1463)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1463)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader$.loadMetadata(ReadWrite.scala:587)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$SharedReadWrite$.$anonfun$load$3(Pipeline.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.$anonfun$instrumented$1(Instrumentation.scala:191)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.instrumented(Instrumentation.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$SharedReadWrite$.load(Pipeline.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelReader.$anonfun$load$7(Pipeline.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.MLEvents.withLoadInstanceEvent(events.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.MLEvents.withLoadInstanceEvent$(events.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation.withLoadInstanceEvent(Instrumentation.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelReader.$anonfun$load$6(Pipeline.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.$anonfun$instrumented$1(Instrumentation.scala:191)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.instrumented(Instrumentation.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelReader.load(Pipeline.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelReader.load(Pipeline.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLReadable.load(ReadWrite.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLReadable.load$(ReadWrite.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$.load(Pipeline.scala:337)

Here are my dependencies in pom:
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <spring-boot.version>2.6.13</spring-boot.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.baomidou</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-plus-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--spark-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--spark_sql-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--hadoop-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--scala-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--spark解析xml依赖包 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-xml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-xml_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--spark-mlib-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- janio-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.16</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

And I noticed that if I directly design spark mlib models to train and predict values instead of loading local spark pipeline models, the program works well.
At first, I added the dependency of hadoop in the pom, but the question still exists. And you can see my pom above. Then I searched for the question and found that maybe the key to solve the quesion is related to wiutils.exe. And I once saw the question when I wanted to run my local spark in Windows 11 a year ago. After that I download the winutils.exe and placed it in the bin of my spark. But now spark is imported in maven, I can not find the proper path to put winutils.
Could anyone help? pls!

The error is caused by Spark detecting it is on Windows and trying to call native functions from the hadoop.dll.  You can download the dll from a number of locations but here is one example: https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils/tree/master
Place the dll file in a directory on your path or add the directory you placed the dll in to your path. That should get you past the error you are seeing.
